# Trigger Child component method when prop changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a child functional component to update when a Parent component changes a value in its state that I'm passing to a this child component as a prop.

The child component "receives" the value correctly and displays the prop value, but the method does not run again.

Child component

```
import React from 'react'

const MyCustomTable = props => {
  const {
    data = [],
  } = props

  const finalData = getSalesData() //This is the method i want to run when the selectedMonth prop updates

  const getSalesData = () => {
    //It does some calculations with the prop called data
  }

  return (
    <Box>
        {JSON.stringify(props.selectedMonth.value)}
        <Table
            data={finalData}
        />
    </Box>
  )
}

SalesByFamilyBU.propTypes = {}

export default MyCustomTable
```

The JSON.stringify line displays the changes correctly but I guess the getSalesData() is not automatically executed.

Comment: How do you know that method doesn't fire? try adding `console.log()` inside the `getSalesData` function

Comment: It would help if you defined your function before you tried to call it.

Answer (score 0):

While you could use some lifecycle method or the `useEffect` hook to achieve what you want to do, I would rather use a functional approach.

In your example, finalData is a derived value of `props.data` and `props.selectedMonth`. You could then compute finalData directly from these props:

```
const MyCustomTable = props => {
    const {
        data = [],
    } = props;

    const filterData = (data, selectedMonth) => data.map(dataPoint => ({
        ...dataPoint,
        selected: dataPoint.month === selectedMonth,
    }); // or whatever, use your function logic here

    const finalData = filterData(data, props.selectedMonth.value);

    return (...);
};
```

---

If you really needed to call a function each time data is changing (ex. to fetch data elsewhere) you could use something like that:

```
const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
    const [finalData, setFinalData] = useState([]);

    const myFunction = () => {
        const newData = ... // whatever you need to do
        setFinalData(newData);
    };

    useEffect(myFunction, [data]);

    return ...;
};
```